# "spring rake" runs specs regardless of what rake task is specified

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spring, rake

If I use `spring rake`, it runs my project specs to matter what `rake` task is specified. It just completely ignores whatever is specified at the command line and runs the specs. Here's an example:

```
$ spring rake routes
/Users/rsilva/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby -I/Users/rsilva/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-    p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.2/lib:/Users/rsilva/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-support-3.1.0/lib /Users/rsilva/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.2/exe/rspec --pattern spec/\*\*\{,/\*/\*\*\}/\*_spec.rb
Run options: exclude {:expensive=>true, :migration=>true}
# then runs all the project specs
```

If I don't use `spring`, it works fine:

```
$ bundle exec rake routes
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern  Controller#Action
# then prints out all the routes
```

I'm using Spring outside of my Gemfile (I did `gem install spring`).

Here's the versions of `spring` and `spring-commands-rspec` I'm using:

```
$ gem list --local | grep -P 'spring'
spring (1.1.3)
spring-commands-rspec (1.0.2)
```

Here's my `~/.spring.rb`:

```
$ cat ~/.spring.rb
require 'spring-commands-rspec'
```

How do I get `spring rake` to execute the task specified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like rake is just executing the default task regardless of arguments passed. This seems to be an issue with rake 10.4.0 and spring. Try upgrading rake to 10.4.1.

https://github.com/rails/spring/issues/366